# remove only the first entries if they are zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series that looks like this:

```
df['column_3'].head(10)

0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.1
6    0.0
7    0.1
8    0.1
9    0.0
```

I would like to remove only the first appearances of zeros, so in this example only rows 0 - 4. The number of zeros in the beginning of the series may vary and I only want to remove the zeros that come before the first instance of a non-zero entry. When I did this:

```
df[df['column_3'] != 0.0]
```

It removes all zeros, no matter the placement, which is not what I want.

I want it to look like this:

```
5    0.1
6    0.0
7    0.1
8    0.1
9    0.0
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m curious, what is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cumsum` is suitable for this situation:

```
df[df['column_3'].ne(0).cumsum().gt(0)]
```

Output:

```
   column_3        
5       0.1
6       0.0
7       0.1
8       0.1
9       0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
df[(df['column_3'].eq(0).cumprod().eq(0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to find the first row which is not zero and filter only on the rows that are after this row.

```
first_non_zero = df.column_3.to_numpy().nonzero()[0][0]
df.loc[first_non_zero:,]
```

Output is

```
   column_3        
5       0.1
6       0.0
7       0.1
8       0.1
9       0.0
```